# how to change row color using mysql query in gridview rowOption using yii2

Tags: php, html, mysql, yii2

I want to change row color as per MySQL query where expiry date is greater than current date and less than within month.

```
'rowOptions'=>function($model) {
  if($model['expirydate'] >= '2018-08-10') {
    return ['class' => 'danger'];
  }
},
```

How can I use below condition in rowOption to highlight upcoming expiry domain row--

```
$domains=Domains::find()
->Where('expirydate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')
->andWhere(['or',['status'=> 'Active'],['status'=> 'Pending Transfer']])
->orderBy(['expirydate' => SORT_ASC])
->all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in PHP, and you can use the `\DateTime()` class for comparing the dates between the range

```
[
    'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
        $db_date = new DateTime($model->expirydate);

        $range_start = new DateTime();
        $range_end = new DateTime();
        $range_end->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));

        //if between range 
        if ($db_date >= $range_start && $db_date <= $range_end) {
            return[
                'class' => 'green'
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                'class' => 'red'
            ];
        }
    }
]
```